# Taking contrapositive of the statement "If $G$ is of even order, then there exists an element $x \in G$ such that $x \neq e$ and $x^2=e.$"

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

**Statement :**

If $G$ is of even order, then there exists an element $x \in G$ such that $x \neq e$ and $x^2=e.$

I am doing it as

1. $\forall x\in G (x=e $ or $ x^2 \neq e) $ $\implies G$ is of odd order
2. $\forall x(\neq e) \in G$ such that $ (x^2 \neq e) $ $\implies G$ is of odd order

Which of these is correct  ? Thanks

Comment: Because $e^2=e$, the second option doesn't need $x\neq e$. The contrapositive is, if $G$ has no element of order $2$, then $G$ has odd order. This is 1.

Comment: @DietrichBurde so basically it's : For all non identity elements of G are  $x ^2 \neq e$ implies G is of odd order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only part that you are not sure of is the negation of "there exists an element $x\in G$ such that $x\neq e$ and $x^2=e$".

Formally, this can be written as:
$$
\exists x\in G (x\neq e\land x^2=e) \tag{$P$}
$$
Then we can negate this statement mechanically:
$$
\begin{align*}
\neg P &\equiv
\forall x\in G \neg(x\ne e \land x^2=e) \\
&\equiv \forall x\in G (x=e \lor x^2\neq e)
\end{align*}
$$
This is your option 1.

Your option 2 is ill-formed.
If you want to express an if-then statement,
i.e. a statement of the form $A\implies B$,
then $A$ and $B$ must be statements themselves.
In your option 2,
$A$ is
$$
\text{$\forall x(\neq e)\in G$ such that $x^2\neq e$}
$$
and $B$ is "$G$ is of odd order".
However, $A$ is not a statement.
What does it assert?
If you want to express a "for all" statement,
it must be $\forall x\ C$, where $C$ is a statement.
Inside $A$, what should $C$ be?
If you remove the words "such that" in $A$,
then it becomes a statement.
It asserts that any non-identity element in $G$ does not have a square equal to the identity.

Assume that you removed "such that" in $A$.
Then $A$ becomes equivalent to $\neg P$.
This is true because
$$
\neg S\lor T \equiv S\implies T
$$
and thus
$$
\begin{align*}
\forall x(\neq e)\in G (x^2\neq e)
&\equiv
\forall x\in G (x\neq e \implies x^2\neq e) \\
&\equiv
\forall x\in G (x=e \lor x^2\neq e) \\
&\equiv \neg P
\end{align*}
$$
so option 1 is equivalent to the corrected option 2.

Comment: So in this i have to make two cases to solve the Question ? –

Comment: If by "solve the question" you mean proving the statement, then you do not necessarily have to make two cases. There are many ways you can prove a statement.

Comment: For example, if I were to prove this, I wouldn't consider the contrapositive to begin with. I would directly find an order 2 element in an even order group. In fact, I suspect that this statement has been proved many times on the site.

Comment: yes thanks. this can be proved by Lagrange i believe. But i havenot reached to that point yetso i took contrapositive approach (indicated in Pinter's book)

Comment: You don't actually need Lagrange's theorem for this. It can be proved by considering the map $x\mapsto x^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your Option 1 is the correct contrapositive. However this translation is not really making sense:

> so basically it's : For all non identity elements of $G$ are $x^2≠e$ implies $G$ is of odd order.

Option 1 reads: If each element $x$ of $G$ is such that $x=e $ or $ x^2 \neq e,$ then $G$ is of odd order.

Comment: So in this i have to make two cases  to solve the Question ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. In any case, the contrapositive's LHS/condition is that `whichever element of G that you take, it must either be the identity or its square is not the identity`. This is different from saying that `every element of G is the identity  or  the square of every element of G is not the identity`.